# Conditional projection with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to do conditional projection with LINQ to SQL? Let's say I have one SQL table called PersonTable. In C#, I have a few classes:

```
public interface Person
{
 int employeeType; //1 is employee, 2 is manager
 String name;
}
```

and two derived classes. For simplicity sake:

```
public class Employee : Person {}
public class Manager : Person {}
```

Now, I want to use LINQ to SQL to project to the appropriate derived class based on employeeType:

```
IQueryable<IPerson> = PersonTable.Select(x => //x.employeeType == 1 ? new Employee { } : x == 2 {new Manager {} )
```

This would be ok for this situation, but I have a situation where I'm trying to instantiate 7 different possible derived types, so the conditional would get long and ugly really fast. Also, my real world scenario, the interface/derived classes have 15 or so properties to populate; which would also get long and ugly quickly.

My first attempt was to write an Expression Tree which returned the appropriate type, but that doesn't work because I need to know the value of the parameter expression to call Expression.MemberInit correctly. What solution might be best for a large conditional initialization like this with LINQ to SQL.

I can't use Table Inheritance, because I'm creating data transfer objects within the projections. I've also thought about using where and union, but the expression tree route seems more intriguing in that I'd have one spot to maintain the code instead of every time a new derived class is introduced - if this is an even an option.

Comment: Is a factory not practical here? Perhaps a dependency-injection framework to help you out? I don't fully understand the requirements other than you (understandably) don't want to have a big, nasty if/else string.

Comment: A factory is not possible here. This is happening in a LoadAll method of my DAL where I'm projecting to domain objects. LINQ to SQL won't like me calling into factory.

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly. You're mixing your filtering with your selecting too much. It's really not a good idea to do such a thing. You'd be better off doing some outer joins and bringing back an anonymous type (with a bunch of NULLs) and casting things in your application code.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out a bad solution here for you. What is `x`? Is it something predetermined in code or is it a column in PersonTable?

Comment: I was afraid of your comment above. This is what's currently being done now. The base class isn't abstract although it really should be. X in this case is an entry being projected from the PersonTable drug onto the DBML designer. I believe it's just a Table type (not in front of the computer at the moment, so I can't look).

Comment: This can easily be done in Entity Framework with [Table Per Hierarchy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96185/Table-Per-Hierarchy-Inheritance-in-Entity-Framewor) and `.OfType()`. But Im not sure if it can be done in LinQ-To-SQL, which is deprecated anyways.

Comment: I dont think table per hierarchy would work for me, at least in the examples I've looked at. Since this is being called in the DAL LoadAll (bringing back a bunch of different type of people) and initializing type specific data transfer objects, the Select call would still have to check the type of table that the discriminator returned to determine what type of Person DTO to instantiate.

Comment: Have you tried making use of variables of type `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>`? You can do some cool tricks with those while still playing nicely with execution-deferred SQL queryies.

Comment: @Jaxidian I have, but do do the dynamic lambda generation in the Expression, I need to know what the value of the employeeId is which I don't think is possible. The expression tree ends up looking something like this (renaming the Person Interface to IPerson to avoid confusion) `Expression<Func<Person, IPerson>> expr = ???` I need the employeeType value at this point so I can do `int employeeTypeVal = typeof(whateverwaspassedin).GetProperty("employeeType).GetValue(???, null); switch (employeeTypeVal) { case: 1 = Expression.MemberInit(typeof(Employee), //binding created elsewhere)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this,

```
PersonTable.Where(p => p.employeeType == 1)
    .Select(p => new Employee { ... })
    .Cast<IPerson>()
    .Concat(
        PersonTable.Where(p => p.employeeType == 2)
            .Select(p => new Manager { ... })
            .Cast<IPerson>());
```

you could also try,

```
PersonTable.Select(p => 
     p.employeeType == 1 ? (IPerson)(new Employee { ... }) :
     p.employeeType == n ? (IPerson)(new Other { ... }) :
     (IPerson)(new Manager { ... }));
```

or, if it didn't need to be `IQueryable`,

```
PersonTable.AsEnumerable().Select(p => {
    switch(p.employeeType)
    {
        case 2:
            return Manager { ... };

        default:
            return Employee { ... };   
    }});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has to to be `IQueryable` since this is consumed by a controller which needs to limit results that come back. I don't think there's going to be a way to do this without repeating a ton of code unfortunately.

Comment: I tried your first example, and it didn't work. It threw an System.NotSupportException: Types in Union or Concat cannot be constructed with hierarchy. I tried casting the results to Enumerable<IPerson> when calling `Concat()`, but then received `NullReferenceException: value cannot be null`. So I added null-coalescs to return empty Enumerables, which also didn't help. Did I find a problem that cannot be solved using LINQ to SQL? :)

Comment: @Furynation looks likely, I'm stumped but, your table has the same schema for every row ... might be simpler to do the casting client side.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. The Person class is not abstract (even though it really should be) and I cast where necessary. Thanks for the input!